How to fetch WordPress records using API
I have this URL : https://www.cambridgehealthug.com/wp-json/wp/v2/search that seems to only bring 8 records from the WordPress database which is full of many other posts.
I tried https://www.cambridgehealthug.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=${searchinput} because I wanted to get specific records according an alphabetical letter like A, but when I query, it shows results starting with H only and they are persistent.
Below is the code. I am using JavaScript to fetch the posts
// Capture user input and send it to the server for processing
  document.getElementById('searchInput').addEventListener('input', async () => {
    var searchInput = this.value;
    if (document.getElementById('searchInput') === '') {
      // If the search input is empty, hide the results
      document.getElementById('searchResults').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      await fetch(`https://www.cambridgehealthug.com/wp-json/wp/v2/search`)//??search=${searchInput}&filter[orderby]=title&filter[order]=asc
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(posts => {
          console.log('Posts retrieved:', posts);
          if(posts === " " || !posts) 
          {
              return document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = "No records found";
          }
          else{
          displayPostTitles(posts, searchInput); // Display the retrieved post titles based on the search input
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // Handle errors
          console.error('Error fetching posts:', error);
        });
    }
  });

 // Function to display the retrieved post titles based on the search input
  const displayPostTitles = (posts, searchInput) => {
      if(!posts && !searchInput) return null
    // Convert the search input to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison
    const searchTerm = searchInput.toLowerCase().trim();
    // Filter the post titles based on the search input
    const filteredTitles = posts.filter((post) => {
      // Convert the post title to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison
      const title = post.title.rendered.toLowerCase().trim();
      return title.includes(searchTerm);
    });

    // Display the filtered post titles as links in the user interface
    let titlesList = '<ul>';
    filteredTitles.forEach((post) => {
      titlesList += '<li><a href="' + post.link + '">' + post.title.rendered + '</a></li>';
    });
    titlesList += '</ul>';
    document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = titlesList;
  }
});


Make sure to include: ?per_page=100 to the "fetch" url.
